# Explicitly Set Content-Type Headers For Get Operation in HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

Is there a way in which I can explicitly set the `Content-Type` header values when performing a `GET` with `HttpClient` ?

I realise this breaks 1.1 protocol, but I am working with a API that does not conform to it, and REQUIRES I set a `Content-Type` Header.

I have tried this with to no avail...

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
   var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://example.com");

   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded+v1.3");

   await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)
}
```

I've inspected the `DefaultRequestHeaders` after the `TryAddWithoutValidation` is added, and it does not seem to be setting the `Content-Type` value.

If I try to set the Content-Type of the httpRequestMessage (by setting `httpRequestMessage.Content = ...`, I get the following error:

```
Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
```

Is there a way that I can explicitly set the `Content-Type` for a `GET` operation using the HttpClient?

Comment: As a workaround I've been able to use `WebClient` in the meantime.

Comment: @ZenCoder. This does not set the `Content-Type` header. Only the `Accept` header.

Comment: There is no body for a GET operation, so there is no need to set the Content-Type. The API should be corrected, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my findings i concluded the HttpClient is very restrictive in terms of the protocol rules. I also reflected through the implementation DLL and i couldn't find anything that it would indicate that it allows protocol violations.

GET requests shouldn't have content-type headers, and the HttpClient is enforcing that rule.

I think the exception message when you try to set the content-type header is self-descriptive:

> System.InvalidOperationException: **Misused header name**. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

Also if you use set the content body you get one more self-descriptive message:

> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: **Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type**.

Since you are willing to violate HTTP rules for GET requests i am pretty sure your only option is to stick with the less restrictive WebClient, which works in that scenario.

Comment: Yeah sorry I need to repeat myself - the API I'm integrating with is not conforming to HTTP specification. They require a `GET` operation, supplying a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Right. Sorry. I have rewritten my response.

Comment: thanks, I had a feeling that might be the only option. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

It's possible - and very dirty - to override the library behavior with a bit of reflection and by introducing a `DelegatingHandler` that you give as argument to the `HttpClient` constructor. See the code below.

```
public class HmacAuthenticatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public HmacAuthenticatingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) 
       : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        // HACK: Set 'Content-Type' even for GET requests
        var invalidHeaders = (HashSet<string>)typeof(HttpHeaders)
            // use "_invalidHeaders" for System.Net.Http v2.2+
            .GetField("invalidHeaders", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(request.Headers);
        invalidHeaders.Remove("Content-Type");

        request.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working with .Net Framework version 4.0, System.Net.Http version 2.2.29.0 but working with 2.0.0.0

Comment: @prem change "invalidHeaders" to be "_invalidHeaders"

Answer (score 3):

Although of no help to you right now, it does look like a future release of the .NET framework may support this type of protocol violation with the addition of an [AddWithoutValidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204926) method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204926

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding headers to content header (as apposed as a request header)
see [here](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2013/11/26/setting-content-type-fails-with-invfalidoperationexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation with an API I need to call, and I was able to work around it by setting the content to an empty `StringContent`:

```
httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.ASCII, "application/json");
```

This sends both a `Content-Type` and a `Content-Length` header (with value of `0`), which the API I'm calling is ok with. This wouldn't work if the API rejects requests with a `Content-Length` header.

I'm using .NET Core 3.1. It looks like the version used by OP did not support setting the `Content` property on a GET request.